# Why this Excel VBA "if equals to empty value" always report an error?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the VBA code below.
I want to use the conditions if cell(T, ?) is not empty and cell(E, ?) is empty then delete the entire row.
But when I test it, there will be an error says like "Error 13, Objects do not match".
Why did this error happen? How to fix it?
Thank you so much!

```
Sub test()
    Dim del As Integer
    For del = 2 To 350
        If Range("T" & del) <> "" And Range("E" & del) = "" Then
            Rows(del).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next del
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `IsEmpty`  to test - or just use a filter here.

Comment: Range("T" & del) is range not value

Comment: try to use Range("T" & del).value